# Untranslatable data in laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, utf-8

I am storing an .csv file in database. Database is using postgresql. But when inserting I get this error in my laravel website.

> SQLSTATE[22P05]: Untranslatable character: 7 ERROR:  character with
>   byte sequence 0xe2 0x88 0x92 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in
>   encoding "EUC_JP"

I am not converting the format of any data in my controller. I reckon it automatically translates before inserting into the database.

I checked in the internet and found that the byte sequence is for `−`(double byte dash) character. EUC-JP has byte sequence `A1 DD` which will provide the same character. So it should have an equivalent.

What should I do?